# Adjust Bootstrap input element's help text

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need to adjust the spacing of the help text that follows an input (note the extra spacing between `Work Telephone` and its descriptive text):

[image]

The `erb`:

```
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputWorkEmail">Work Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputWorkEmail" name="contact[work_email]" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="first.last@company.web" value="<%= @contact[:work_email] %>">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Work email address of the contact.</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputWorkTelephone">Work Telephone</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputWorkTelephone" name="contact[work_telephone]" aria-describedby="telephoneHelp" placeholder="800-555-1212" value="<%= @contact[:work_telephone] %>">
    </div>
    <small id="telephoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Work telephone number of the contact.</small>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space between the input and the help text is caused by the class `mb-3` in your input group.

```
.mb-3, .my-3 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem!important;
}
```

if you remove that class, the margin will be gone:

```
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputWorkEmail">Work Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputWorkEmail" name="contact[work_email]" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="first.last@company.web" value="<%= @contact[:work_email] %>">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Work email address of the contact.</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputWorkTelephone">Work Telephone</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputWorkTelephone" name="contact[work_telephone]" aria-describedby="telephoneHelp" placeholder="800-555-1212" value="<%= @contact[:work_telephone] %>">
    </div>
    <small id="telephoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Work telephone number of the contact.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

The corrected code is on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/28299/)

Comment: If you want to keep the class, just modify using the style attribute